# NextJS 13 in Azure: process.env.{SETTING_NAME} in server components is undefined

Tags: azure, next.js13

I upgraded to NextJS v13 from v12. I thought components inside the src/app folder are server components by default but when I try to use the values from process.env after deploying with Azure, its returning undefined for those configuration settings.

It works when I run it locally maybe because those settings are in a .env file but after deployment it should get it from the Azure configuration settings. Here is the sample page:

src/app/page.tsx

```
import SampleClientView from '@components/components/client/SampleClientView'; // This has 'use client';

const SamplePage = () => {
  const configOne = process.env.CONFIG_ONE;
  const configTwo = process.env.CONFIG_TWO;

  return (
    <SampleClientView
      configOne={configOne}
      configTwo={configTwo}
    />
  );
};

export default SamplePage;
```

Comment: define `SETTING_NAME` and its value in `environment variables` of your azure web app portal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using incorrect NextJS configuration values and was exporting my pages wrong. To make this work. In my next.config.js, I changed *appDir: true* to *serverActions: true*:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  experimental: { serverActions: true },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

and for some reason I also had to change how I exported my pages in page.tsx:

```js
import { headers } from 'next/headers';
import SampleClientView from '@components/components/client/SampleClientView'; // This has 'use client';

export default function UserRedirectPage() {
  console.log('Initializing UserRedirectPage...');
  const configOne = process.env.CONFIG_ONE;
  const configTwo = process.env.CONFIG_TWO;
  
  const headersList = headers();
  const host = headersList.get('x-forwarded-host') || headersList.get('host');
  const path = headersList.get('referer') || '';

  console.log(
    `${new Date().toLocaleString()} - Host=${host}, path=${path} configOne=${configOne} configTwo=${configTwo}`
  );

  return (
    <SampleClientView
      configOne={configOne}
      configTwo={configTwo}
    />
  );
}
```